# Blazor EventCallback<MyType<T>>

Tags: c#, blazor, event-handling

Given the following EventCallback definition

`public EventCallback<MenuAction<TRowData>> OnMenuItemClicked { get; set; } = default!;`

This handler:

`private void OnMenuItemClicked(MenuAction<UserQualificationVM> action)`

And this event subscription:

`<SearchResultsGridComponent OnMenuItemClicked="@((action) => OnMenuItemClicked(action))">`

I get the error

**Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to MenuAction < UserQualificationVM > '**

If I change the signature of the EventCallback to

`private void OnMenuItemClicked(object)`

and amend all of the associated code I don't get the error.

My question is - is this type of EventCallback definition, with a typed object, actually allowed? And if so what am I doing wrong?

MenuAction is defined as follows:

```
    public class MenuAction<TRowData>
{
    public int ActionId { get; set; }
    public string MenuText { get; set; } = "";

    public Expression<Func<TRowData, bool>>? PredicateExpression { get; set; }

    public string ShowMenuItemPredicate { get; set; } = default!;

    public object? Data { get; set; }
}
```

A list of MenuAction items is passed into the grid component, and the grid component itself is provided with a type parameter - in this case UserQualificationVM.

The grid component is defined as follows:

```
[CascadingTypeParameter(nameof(TRowData))]
public partial class SearchResultsGridComponent<TRowData>
{
     [Parameter]
    public ICollection<TRowData> Items { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

The grid is built in HTML as follows:

```
<SearchResultsGridComponent Items="UserQualificationVMs" OnMenuItemClicked="@((action) => OnMenuItemClicked(action))">

    <SearchResultsGridColumnBase Expression="e => e.QualTypeTitle" Title="Qualification Type" />
    <SearchResultsGridColumnBase Expression="e => e.QualName" Title="Title" />
    <SearchResultsGridColumnBase Expression="e => e.DateAttained" Title="Date Achieved" ColumnDataType="GridColumnDataType.ShortDate" />
    <SearchResultsGridColumnBase Expression="e => e.BodyName" Title="Awarding Body" />
    <SearchResultsGridColumnBase Expression="e => e.QualGrade" Title="Grade" />
    <SearchResultsGridColumnBase Expression="e => e.QualPlaceOfStudy" Title="Place of Study" />
    <SearchResultsGridKebabMenuColumn MenuActions="_menuActions" Title="KebabMenu" ShowInColumnSelector=false ShowTitleInHeader=false />

</SearchResultsGridComponent>
```

The Razor in the grid iterates through it's rows and renders HTML provided by overriding the RenderFragment method of the individual rows. In the case of the kebab menu column, the code is as follows:

```
internal override RenderFragment<TRowData> CellTemplate
{
    get
    {
        return cellTemplate ??= (rowData => builder =>
        {
            BuildCellTemplate(rowData, builder);

        });
    }
}

private void BuildCellTemplate(TRowData rowData, RenderTreeBuilder builder)
{
//Open TD element
StartTableCell(builder, rowData, "KebabMenu");

builder.OpenElement(0, "div");

builder.OpenElement(2, "button");
builder.AddAttribute(3, "type", "button");
builder.CloseElement();

builder.OpenElement(4, "ul");

int index = 0;

foreach (var menuAction in MenuActions)
{
    if (menuAction.PredicateExpression is not null)
    {
        if (!menuAction.PredicateExpression.Compile()(rowData))
        {
           continue;
         }
        builder.OpenElement(5, "li");
        builder.OpenElement(6, "a");
        builder.AddAttribute(7, "href", "#");
        builder.AddEventPreventDefaultAttribute(8, "onclick", true);
        builder.AddAttribute(8, "onclick", new EventCallbackFactory().Create(this, (args) => MenuItemClicked(menuAction, rowData)));
        builder.AddContent(9, menuAction.MenuText);
        builder.CloseElement();
        builder.CloseElement();

        index++;
    }

    builder.CloseElement();

    builder.CloseElement();

    //Close TD element
    EndTableCell(builder);
}

private void MenuItemClicked(MenuAction<TRowData> action, TRowData rowData)
{
    action.Data = rowData;
    OwnerGrid.MenuItemClicked(action);
}
```

As you can see the kebab menu column creates an event callback which calls up to the owning grid. The owning grid then fires it's own event callback:

```
internal async Task MenuItemClicked(MenuAction<TRowData> action)
{
    await OnMenuItemClicked.InvokeAsync(action);
}
```

Comment: How is MenuAction defined?

Comment: Incomplete. Where does UserQualificationVM come from?

Comment: Maybe also give us more code from your GridComponent

Comment: Thanks for the MenuAction code. Could you also give us the razor for your GridComponent

Comment: Well dont you need to define the TRowData type when you call the GridComponent?

Comment: Also shouldnt it be enough to subscribe like this: `OnMenuItemClicked="OnMenuItemClicked"`

Comment: Also where do you execute the method/when do you raise the event in your code?

Comment: The grid works out it's TRowData type by the type of the Items parameter that is passed in. And yes, it should be enough to have 'OnMenuItemclicked=OnMenuItemClicked', but this gives a similar error hence the expansion to explore the issue.

Comment: @Germgh0st yeah I see your frustration now. It strange to me as well. The fix here is to add the TRowData def as well, but I fully get why you feel like that shouldnt be needed. The rest of the code is able to just pull the Type out of the List, and when we hover over the callback we see that its able to do so as well. This is indeed a weird issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define the `TRowData` type like [SMSTJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22976106/smstj) suggested:

```
<SearchResultsGridComponent TRowData="UserQualificationVM"
                            Items="UserQualificationVMs"
                            OnMenuItemClicked="OnMenuItemClicked">
    ...
</SearchResultsGridComponent>
```

Comment: It is a interesting thing however. I get what they are going for. The component takes the type out of the list no problem it just struggles with the callback. But when we leave out the TRowData def and get our error and hover over the callback def, the callback recongises that it is of MenuAction<UserQualificationVM>

Comment: So it is kinda weird that it doesnt recognise the parameter as that type instead of object

Comment: This ^. The grid gets it's type from the parameter passed in and if you hover over the 'OnMenuClicked' callback parameter it shows the correct type. So it is weird that this type inference is not applied to the EventCallback. Adding the type explicity to the grid tag has indeed solved the issue, thank you :)

Comment: [Related GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/39734). Looks like `OnMenuItemClicked="(UserQualificationVM action) => OnMenuItemClicked(action)">` without `TRowData="UserQualificationVM"` also works.

Comment: I can confirm that using (MenuAction<UserQualificationVM> action) => OnMenuItemClicked(action) without passing in the type explicity also works.

Comment: The Razor markup goes through two compilations.  The Razor -> C# class and then the normal C# compilation.  I think the problem is in inferring T at compile time. Parameters, including `EventCallbacks`, are assign runtime when the component is actually rendered.  Generics can be cascaded  which is what some composite components such as grids do- see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/generic-type-support?view=aspnetcore-8.0#cascaded-generic-type-support

Comment: The generic is being cascaded, as per my code example. The type inference works even at design time - mousing over the OnMenuItemClicked parameter shows the correct type in the tooltip. But at runtime it doesn't seem to be inferred correctly for the EventCallback. It's been acknowledged as a bug, link above.